# Turf.within is not working

Tags: ajax, leaflet, turfjs

I have a function to get the nearest points (farmers) to a specific point(customer),i made a buffer around the customer with distance from the user then i am using turf.within to get all the points(farmers) inside this buffer.
It works fine if i give the array of coordinates in the feature collection in the variable `searchWithin`,but when i gave it as a variable (array) which is in this case the points of the buffer `bufresult` it doesn't work.

```
function Find_Nearest()
{
//getting the orderid to get the customer id
var select1 = document.getElementById('OrderId');
var Order_ID = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text;
var Cust_Name = document.getElementById('CustName').textContent;

//to check the distance entered by user
var select = document.querySelector('input[name="optradio"]:checked').value;
var dist=document.getElementById('dist').value; 

if (select == "EnterRange") 
{
    if (dist == null || dist == "" || isNaN(dist) ) 
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid range");
        document.getElementById('dist').focus() ;   
    }
    else { distance=dist;}
}
else { distance=select;}

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"CustomerID_geojson.php",
    data:{'Cust_Name': Cust_Name} ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) 
    {
        var unit = 'kilometers';
        var buffered = turf.buffer(response, distance, unit);
        var bufresult = new Array();
        bufresult.push(buffered.geometry.coordinates);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'allfarmers_geojson.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) 
        {
            var searchWithin = {
              "type": "FeatureCollection",
              "features": [
                {
                  "type": "Feature",
                  "properties": {},
                  "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": bufresult //the problem is here
                //    [[
                //      [126.5443329669793,8.71772],
                //      [126.17866648348965,9.34375583885896],
                //      [125.44733351651035,9.34375583885896],
                //      [125.08166703302071,8.71772],
                //      [125.44733351651035,8.091684161141039],
                //      [126.17866648348965,8.091684161141039],
                //      [126.5443329669793,8.71772]
                //    ]]
                  }
                }
              ]
            };

            console.log(bufresult);
            console.log(searchWithin);

            var ptsWithin = turf.within(data, searchWithin);
            console.log(ptsWithin);         
            geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(ptsWithin).addTo(mymap);
            mymap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
        }
        });
     }
});
}
```

Comment: @FranceImage  can you check this ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

`var bufresult = new Array();`
and
`bufresult.push(buffered.geometry.coordinates);`

with

`bufresult = buffered.geometry.coordinates`

I think the issue may be that you are initializing an array (`bufresult`) and then pushing the buffered geometry coordinates into that array. You could actually just skip the `bufresult` variable all together and just plug the `buffered.geometry.coordinates` variable into where you're using `bufresult`. Let me know if this doesn't work for you. Could you also include the error that you're getting?

Comment: ...i can't thank you enough...it finally works..can you tell me how to check if the result from the turf.within is Zero or not?

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it is working for you now. All you need to do to check if turf.within found any points inside the polygon is do `result = turf.within(points, polygons)` and then `if result.features.length > 0`. The length of the features will be 0 if no points were within the polygons. Otherwise it will be at least 1.